# How can I insert/update with a related table?

Tags: mysql

I have these three tables:

- User

  - ID (KEY)
  - ID_Facebook (Unique)
  - Nickname
- Game

  - ID (KEY)
  - Name
- IsPlaying

  - ID (KEY)
  - ID_user (Unique)
  - ID_game
  - Time_UP

You should also do that if the key exists then update. Then the only values are known as:

The table has to be **isplaying** to update or insert.

> User.ID_Facebook = 2131234
>
> Game.Name="Name of the game"
>
> IsPlaying.Time_UP="0000-00-00 00:00:00"

**Example SQL (Doesn't work)**

```
INSERT INTO isplaying (ID_User, ID_Game, Time_UP)

VALUES((SELECT ID FROM User WHERE ID_FACEBOOK=2131234), (SELECT ID FROM Game WHERE Name="Name of the game"), "2016-05-18 00:00:00")

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ID_Game=, Time_UP="2016-05-18 00:00:00"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO isplaying (ID_User, ID_Game, Time_UP) 

VALUES((SELECT ID From user WHERE ID_Facebook=2131234),(SELECT ID From game WHERE name="NAME OF GAME"), "2016-00-00 00:00:00") 

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ID_Game=(SELECT ID From game WHERE Name="NAME OF GAME"), Time_UP="2016-00-00 00:00:00"
```